# Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks, node-modules, publishing

I created a react js project with Material UI

And then I was building and publishing the whole project with

```
build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file BuildTest/index.js
```

When I installed this module in Client-side(Other Project) I got this problem:

[image]

Module :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = {
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
};

function HigherOrderComponent(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Higher-order component</Button>;
}

HigherOrderComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(HigherOrderComponent);
```

Client-Side:

```
import Mtest from "testmodule";
import React, { Component } from "react";


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Mtest/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In the posted code i can't find any hooks related code snippet, did you missed it?

Comment: please tell us in which component the error is happening

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS no I don't miss any, but if I change Module code, in function return to a simple HTML button, it works well without any error

Comment: @OlivierBoissé in Client-side, App.js ,the component that called the module

Comment: When I search for this, "You might have more than one copy of React in the same app", I found this command line " npm ls react" , and it return 
'clienttest@0.1.0 
 ├── react@16.12.0
      testmodule@1.0.0
          ├── react@16.12.0  extraneous'